# Flexbox is stacking items vertically when I use a fixed position

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Can someone tell me why my items are stacked vertically using Flexbox and direction row inside of a div with a fixed position? Here is a link to a jsfiddle example

http://jsfiddle.net/vCV6T/4/

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="topNav">
            <div class="navBar">
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="mainContent">this is the main content div</div>
        <div id="bottomNav">
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

### CSS

```
#container
{
    z-index:1;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    min-width:0;
    display:flexbox;
    flex-flow:column nowrap;
    background-color:red;
    bottom:0;
}

#topNav
{
    z-index:2;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
}

.navBar
{
    display:flexbox;
    height:40px;
    flex-direction:row;
    background-color:rgba(0, 38, 255,0.5);
    justify-content:center;
}

#mainContent{
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:pink;
}

#bottomNav
{
    z-index:2;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    display:flexbox;
    flex-flow:row nowrap;
    background-color:rgba(0, 38, 255,0.5);
    height:40px;
    width:100%;
}

.item
{
    height:36px;
    width:36px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:brown;
    border:thin solid #000;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You are using the wrong syntax:

`display: flexbox` should be `display:flex`

2) The default values for `flex-direction` is `row` and the default for `flex-wrap` is `noWrap` - ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-flow)) - so your `flex-flow` rules are unnecessary

Here is an updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/vCV6T/7/)**